# Evaluation of hypergeometric function when the argument is sum of two matrices

Tags: hypergeometric-function

If $_pF_q\left(a_1,\cdots,a_p;b_1,\cdots,b_q;A+B\right)$ is a hypergeometric function whose third argument is a sum of two positive definite symmetric matrices, $A$ and $B$, then is there any way to write this function in terms of $A$ and $B$ and not $A+B$?

Comment: If they commute then I guess you could use the binomial expansion